# How to send Keys to an application

Tags: c#

I have a very basic problem, For a game (Dota 2) I want to write a little macro which opens the console, writes "setinfo name ".........................."" into it and then closes it, the hotkey for console is set to '#'. For this I wrote an application which listens for the key 'f' to be pressed, and then send

```
1) '#' (open the console)
2) "messag ebla bla b...."
3) '#' (close the console)
```

everything is working except that it will not open the console (but if the console is already open it will write #messagej.j....# into it when i press f just as wanted)

my code for sending the keys.

```
SendKeys.Send("#");
SendKeys.Send("my message for consol");
SendKeys.Send("#");
```

does anybody know why the hotkeys dont work by sending keys? I thought its an simulation of when the user presses F or Q.

Comment: There has been some debate on tags in the title of questions. Currently we feel tags shouldn't be part of the title. I edited your title.

Answer (score 0):

First thing You should try is adding a "software" delay between keypresses.

```
string MSG = "#yourmessage#";
foreach (object c_loopVariable in MSG) {
    c = c_loopVariable;
    Sendkeys.Send(c);
    sleep(20);

}
```

The other thing to consider - sendkeys do not emulate the keypress at the hardware layer - it is on windows API level, and the DirectX DirectInput., witch most games use for user input processing goes a level further. So it is possible You will not be able to do it this easy.

You should check out more of keybd_event. Ive had better luck using that - as i understand it goes a level deeper than just sendkeys.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

Anyways, I hope u are not going to use this for some spamming in a great game! :)

Comment: Adding a delay won't change anything. And `keybd_event` is how `SendKeys` is implemented. Or possibly `SendInput` which is equivalent.

Comment: i tried to send input with autohotkeys sendinput method, it works, but i have no possibility to embed autohotkey into c#... does anybody know which method autohotkey uses for input injection?